# How do I convert req.sessionID to connect.sid?

Tags: express

I can see the `req.sessionID`, it's like `yeVIo68JZHLb9rvA3Js2MY6RMOo1p29S`.

In the browsers console I can see the `connect.sid` and it looks something like this `s%3AEsvCST_KXoCmyD1ixT1Elksp7WQU5Bwp.a1zlev0vJ0dNESbPCeOXZq3jsPAsAGCS7O0KTyrOTAU`

I took a look at the `cookie-signature` library and it's not ithe same as what I see in `connect.sid` as it has the word "hello" in the signature.

```
var cookie = require('cookie-signature');
var val = cookie.sign('hello', 'tobiiscool');
val.should.equal('hello.DGDUkGlIkCzPz+C0B064FNgHdEjox7ch8tOBGslZ5QI');
```

How do I convert `req.sessionID` to `connect.sid`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto';

const getConnectSid = (sessionID) => {
  return 's.'+sessionID+'.'+crypto.createHmac('sha256', process.env.COOKIE_SECRET) .update(sessionID).digest('base64').replace(/\=+$/, '');
}
```